# Smith Chart - constant resistance circle and infinite resistance at right

Tags: smith-chart

The Smith Chart has a single horizontal line with normalized pure resistance which run from 0 on the left to infinity on the right.

Following the circle which starts at the normalized pure resistance of 1.0 has a constant normalized resistance of 1.0.

However, this circle intercepts the extreme right end of the resistance line at a normalized resistance value of infinity.

I am missing something here.  Is the resistance at this intersection 1.0 or infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circles on the Smith Chart cross the horizontal axis at a certain normalized resistance $R_n$, and at normalized resistance $\infty$.

Traversing these circles (starting from $R_n$) is equivalent to adding a reactance to that resistance. A positive reactance going upwards, and a negative reactance going downwards. This is like adding a reactance $X_n$ in series with a given resistance.

When that reactance goes to $\pm \infty$, you get an open circuit, no matter what the resistive component was originally.